# How to share data between two projects under the same solution

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, global

I have two Windows phone projects under same solution one is of the type `Background Audio Streaming Agent` and the other one is `Blank App (windows phone silverlight)` I have a situation in which I need to share some data between these two projects

> NB: The second project contains a reference to the first project

I have tried

`Global variables` (using static class) but found that the global variables are instantiated and are becoming null when used in the other project

`IsolatedStorage` , found that the two projects are using separate `IsolatedStorageSettings` hence the `keys` and `values` used in one project is not available in the other..

what else can i do ?

Comment: For the config file values they aren't shared between projects, you need to re-create them into the client project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data to a central database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third project that contains shared operations of the two. Make sure the methods that you need to use are public...